# cs50 readability pset6 python this code should count the number of word ,sentence and letter but it didn't

Tags: python, cs50, readability

```
from cs50 import get_string
letter=0
sentence=0
word=0
text = get_string("Text: ")
n = len(text)
for i in range(n):
    if text[i].isalnum()==True:
        letter=letter+1
for i in range(n):
    if text[i].isspace()==True and text[i+1].isalnum()==True:
        word=word+1
for i in range(n):
    if text[i]=="?" or text[i]=="." or text[i]=="!":
        sentence=sentence+1
grade = round (0.0588 * ((100 * letter) / word) - 0.296 * ((100 * sentence) / word) - 15.8)
if grade<1:
    print("Before Grade 1")
elif grade < 16:
    print(f"Grade {grade}")
else :
    print("Grade 16+");
```

https://submit.cs50.io/check50/d3897b249b2ca6ea937d023c25c1607af52ea5cd
the checks is bad

may be i do something false in it

Comment: You need to format the code in the question. Edit the question, select the code, click `{}` in the format bar and it will be formatted. Further, please edit in a description of "it didn't". Provide an example of: the inputted text, the result you expected and the result program gave. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple issues here:

The first one is using *Text* at the beginning (not standard, by the way) vs *text*. That should help you out quite a bit.

The second is that you aren't actually using the *get_string* method. Now, it's possible this works for you; I just threw it into a Juypter Notebook because I wanted to work with it like a REPL. But, assuming not, let's briefly step through it.

Conda environment or pip install with cs50 and run that:

[image]

Runs fine with no errors. Good. Now the first block:

```
letter=0
sentence=0
word=0
Text = get_string("Text: ")
```

That (because I'm using a notebook) evaluates as:

> Text: None

Now, maybe there is something specific you are to use in the cs50 library but I used input -- and changed Text to lower case.

But you were on the right path.

Comment: it could running but it get only 62% ..
am i do something false  in the code to get the grade ?
(i.e. i converted the return type of grede into int)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with the way program counts words. It is doing so by counting spaces (good plan), but

1. How will it count the last word? It won't (because it's not "followed by" a space). You could consider initializing word to 1 (instead of 0).
2. Will it count words in the following passage correctly? Again, no. This `if text[i].isspace()==True and text[i+1].isalnum()==True:` only counts spaces followed by a-z, A-Z, or 0-9. In this case, it will not count the space after "Alice", so word count is incorrect.

> thought Alice "without pictures or conversation?"

A side note: accessing `i + 1` in the `i` loop is generally speaking a very bad idea; it will be outside the range when i reaches the maximum. It hasn't failed in testing because no tested texts end with a space. If you want to see it fail, enter a text that ends with a space.

Comment: 29 word , 1 sentence and 3 letter !

Comment: how should i count it ?

Comment: info added to answer

Answer (score 0):

1) Initialized word to 1;
2) Added the following to assume that a letter is any lower/uppercase character:
for i in range(n):
    if text[i].isalnum() or text[i].isupper() or text[i].islower() == True:
        letter = letter+1
3) Removed for word count:
and text[i+1].isalnum()==True:

Now your code is 10/10!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please improve formatting of your answer. It's hard to read it in its current form.

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing word to 1, removing ‘round’ before CLI, and adding round to you second to last print statement. Example: {round(grade)}

I had similar code, worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Great work, I fixed it with only adding the last part here:

```
if text[i]=="?" or text[i]=="." or text[i]=="!" or text[i]==":":
```

Comment: Hi Rakel, please read up on [writing a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Enjoy your stay here at SO :)

Answer (score 0):

You should assign `word = 1` instead of `word = 0`
(line # 4)